# Replace Alembic Cache Files from py

Tags: python, scripting, alembic

I need to change the FilePath of an already imported Alembic File Cache.

In the UI it is done from the Datablocks>Cache Files>File Path, but I need do it with PY + File Blend + New Path)

1. Search all cache files
2. List
3. Change filepath
4. Save

Any idea???

Answer (score 2):

You can find this in the Python tooltip:

[image: screenshot]

In this example I would change `bpy.data.cache_files['3DSMAX_character_armature.abc'].filepath` to point to the new Alembic file location.

Iterating over all Alembic caches can be done with `for cfile in bpy.data.cache_files.values(): …`